# Geth node not finding peers with Zedboard

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

I've been trying to setup an Ethereum node using geth inside a Zedboard which has Arch Linux ARM installed inside it. I am using the latest version of the binaries for the ARM7 version available in the official page (1.10.15). This is intended to be a proof of authority network using Clique as consensus mechanism. In another PC in the LAN network, I ran the bootnode by:

> ./bootnode -nodekey "./PoA/bootnode/boot.key" -verbosity 7 -nat extip:<My_IP> -addr <My_IP>:30301

And within the Zedboard I ran:

> ./geth --networkid 1234 --nat extip:<Zedboard_IP> --allow-insecure-unlock --datadir "./PoA/node1/data" --bootnodes <enode_url>@<My_IP>:30301 --port 30303 --ipcdisable --syncmode full --http --http.corsdomain "*" --http.port 8545 --unlock <public_address> --password ./PoA/node1/password.txt --mine

However, it is unable to connect to the bootnode, and the terminal log obtained is this:

```
TRACE[02-10|10:10:13.273] >> PING/v4                               id=6bfb333b9895bf0f addr=<Zedboard_IP>:30303 err=nil
TRACE[02-10|10:10:14.205] << FINDNODE/v4                           id=6bfb333b9895bf0f addr=<Zedboard_IP>:30303 err="unknown node"
TRACE[02-10|10:10:14.275] << FINDNODE/v4                           id=6bfb333b9895bf0f addr=<Zedboard_IP>:30303 err="unknown node"
TRACE[02-10|10:10:14.707] << PING/v4                               id=6bfb333b9895bf0f addr=<Zedboard_IP>:30303 err=nil
TRACE[02-10|10:10:14.707] >> PONG/v4                               id=6bfb333b9895bf0f addr=<Zedboard_IP>:30303 err=nil
TRACE[02-10|10:10:14.708] >> PING/v4                               id=6bfb333b9895bf0f addr=<Zedboard_IP>:30303 err=nil
TRACE[02-10|10:10:15.710] << FINDNODE/v4                           id=6bfb333b9895bf0f addr=<Zedboard_IP>:30303 err="unknown node"
```

Other nodes inside the LAN network (ubuntu 18.04) discover each other and can sign blocks and call functions inside the network. Any idea of what could be the issue here? I have alreadt tried to assign --cache and syncmode to snap to the Zedboard, but it is still not working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it is required for all machines in the network to share the same NTP server (or at least have the same synchronization in their system clocks).